# How to use COUNT(column) in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm trying to build this query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(file) AS f FROM user GROUP BY name
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
db[:user].select(:name).count(:file).group(:name)
```

But it doesn't work. How can I add that `COUNT(file) AS f` to the list of `SELECT` operands?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write following:

```
@db[:user].
select{[:name, count(:file___f )]}.
group(:name)
```

Read the docs:

- [`select`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-select)
- [`Aliasing`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html#label-Aliasing)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found:

```
@db[:user]
  .select(:name)
  .select_more{Sequel.as(count(:user__file), :f)}
  .group(:name)
```

Works fine :)